# Why wouldn't "ParseQuery<ParseUser> query=new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("User");" work?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am creating an android app which uses parse. I recently learned about `ParseQuery<>` and applied it to `ParseObject`. I know that there is a method called `parseUser.getQuery()` but if `ParseQuery<>` works for other classes I have created, why wouldn't `ParseQuery<ParseUser> query=new ParseQuery<ParseUser>("User");` work for the User class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because you are passing a string and the SDK is not able to cast a generic type to ParseUser. Try with:

```java
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query=new ParseQuery<ParseUser>(ParseUser);
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand that. Could you provide a clearer explanation

Comment: If you pass a String, the SDK does not know which specific class this is string is related to. So you need to pass ParseObject instead of ParseUser. For example: ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=new ParseQuery< ParseObject >("Score"); or ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=new ParseQuery< ParseObject >("User");

Comment: Edit: `ParseQuery<ParseUser> query=new ParseQuery<ParseUser>(ParseUser);` doesn't work

Comment: It just says expression expected. I think the constructor doesn't accept `ParseUser`

Comment: Please try with this `ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();`